# passing custom options to AuthenticationStateProvider

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Advice?

I have a blazor server application using a custom authentiationstateprovider.  It uses ProtectedSessionStorage to save the autentication state.  Since I may want to reuse this code I want to pass the session key to the constructor but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm thinking something like this:
Program.cs

```
.
.
builder.Services.AddScoped<ProtectedSessionStorage>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>(options => { sessionKey = "abcdef"} );
.
.
```

CustomAuthenticationStateProvider.cs

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{

    private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage _sessionStorage;
    private readonly string _sessionKey;
    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage, sessionKey = "12345")
    {
        _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
        _sessionKey = sessionKey;

    }
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            var userSessionStorageResult = await _sessionStorage.GetAsync<UserSession>(_sessionKey);
      .
      .
      .
     }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

This of course did not work.  Can anyone tell me if I'm even on the right track?

Comment: Add the session key in AppSettings and then access and inject it via the Options pattern.  See this Ms article to show you how it's done - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options

Comment: Thank you MrC.  It took me some reading but I eventually made it setting up appsettings as you said, then builder.Services.Configure<...>( ... ) as in the document and  then injecting the IOptions into my constructor.  Thank you again...

Comment: Good learning exercise!  I would have answered any questions if you had got stuck.  I've added my comment as an Answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the session key in AppSettings and then access and inject it via the Options pattern.

See this Ms article to show you how it's done - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options.